# Rails 3 routing: singular option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, routes

You used to be able to do:

resources :paises, :singular => :pais

But I tried this in Rails and it didn't work. I want to have 'pais_path()' for show and 'paises_path()' for index.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

open your `config/initializers/inflections.rb` file and add this

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'pais', 'paises'
end
```

then your route `resources :paises` will work for you as expected